# Weird animation behaviour while using autolayout in .xib

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I've a custom tableview cell with a right aligned button having following constraints:

1. Trailing space from superview
2. Fixed width
3. Fixed height
4. Top space from superview

[image]

Now when I launch my view controller, this edit icon image fly and settle down at the correct location. How can I remove that animation.

NOTE: This problem is in visible only in certain cells. I've also tried deleting and re-adding the component as well.

Comment: Where are you adding the constraints? Is it in the storyboard or programmatically?

Comment: I'm adding constraints in the .xib file of my custom table view cell.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fixed the problem by updating the frame and then calling the `[self layoutIfNeeded];`
Nothing will work if you miss `[self layoutIfNeeded];` function call after updating your frames.

Answer (score 1):

While working with autolayout, you should always call `[self layoutIfNeeded];` after updating the frame.